# Install urllib2 in Arch Linux

Tags: python, linux, urllib2, archlinux

I am trying to install the urllib2 module in Arch Linux as I need to run a Python code.

The error that the Python code outpus is:

```
File "PiMiner/PiMiner.py", line 3, in <module>
import sys, subprocess, time, urllib2, socket
```

Now, when I runt his code `sudo pacman -S urllib2`, I get `error: target not found: urllib2`

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: What Python version are you using? If 2.x, then `urllib2` does not need to be installed, it's a standard module. If 3.x, then you need to change the imports [accordingly](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ArchLinux, the command `python` defaults to `python3`.  If you neeed to use 2.x, you should run the script with `python2 whatever.py`.

Answer (score 1):

As aelfric5578 said, `python` defaults to `python3`

But if you wish to run it with python3 then you can search the Arch repos with `pacman -Ss urllib` which will a return a list of packages you can `pacman -S`

As a naming scheme, Arch sticks to `python-libname` for python 3 or `python2-libname` for python2, so it's usually a safe bet to `pacman -S python-missinglib`